# On a Zebra printer, what could change the printable width of a label?

Tags: zpl

One of the printers we print to seems to be stuck on a 3 x 2 inch label, even though it has 4 x 2 inch labels in it.

In the ZPL I've set the Print Width, but that isn't doing anything on the affected printer.

Is there something else I need to add to override the labels printable width

edit: The printer properties -> preferences had the label set to 3 x 2. Is there a way to override that? Or will we have to send out some documentation to users telling them to check it manually.

```
^SZ2
^MMT
^MNY
^LL406
^PW815
^LH0,0
^XA
^CFR,15^FO5,20^FDVendor: Unknown Vendor^FS
^CFR,15^FO5,65^FDSurgeon: Theodore Fisher^FS
^CFR,15^FO5,110^FDDate: Fri, Dec 4^FS
^CFR,15^FO280,110^FDTime: 07:30^FS
^CFR,15^FO5,155^FDProcedure: Plif^FS
^CFR,15^FO5,200^FDSide: ^FS
^CFR,15^FO5,245^FDSystem: Spine^FS
^CFR,15^FO5,290^FDTray: Xia instruments^FS
^CFR,15^FO5,335^FD1 of 6^FS
^CFR,15^FO440,140^FDCasechek^FS
^BY2,2,0^FO520,185^BQN,2,6^FD##hCsck0000000000115d/52521^FS
^CFR,15^FO4560,335^FD4445^FS
^XZ
```

[image]

Comment: ^CFR,15^FO4560,335^FD4445^FS looks wrong - ^CFR,15^FO0560,335^FD4445^FS perhaps?

Comment: that was a typo sorry, it is ...^FO460... in the code